# iOS CSS opacity + visibility transition

Tags: css, ios, mobile, safari, css-transitions

Take a look at the following test in a desktop browser ([JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jrpSJ/)):

```css
a {
  background: gray;
  display: block;
  margin: 100px;
  padding: 100px;
}
a span {
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: 0.5s;
  visibility: hidden;
}
a:hover span {
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transition: 0.5s;
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<a href="#">a <span>span</span></a>
```

You hover over the anchor element and the span element fades in like it should.

Now take a look via an iOS device.
Result: it does nothing.

Facts:

- If the transition property is absent, it works.
- If either the opacity or visibility property is absent, it works.
- There is no webkitTransitionEnd event being fired for the opacity or visibility property.

Is there any workaround?

Comment: Have you thought about the missing pointer on an iOS device? There is no hover.

Comment: Actually there is. Test (with the visibility property being absent): http://jsfiddle.net/jrpSJ/1/

Comment: @ott While not a true hover, click  assumes and triggers css:hover on iOS devices.

Comment: http://www.webarnes.ca/2012/04/mobile-safari-bugs-so-far/ - seems to be a bug.

Comment: hi @Dan, can you provide a reference for this claim? I've long been wondering about using CSS:hover on iOS. And how about Android? thanks!

Comment: @tim-peterson no reference just from personal tests, although the hover off is never triggered and it is kinda of unstable.. you can google for some articles http://niteodesign.com/web-design/iphone-ipad-ios-and-the-css-hover-event/

Comment: @Dan i did notice on my iPhone that hover off is a pain, have to click hard most times. thanks for the link, i think i'll just stick with `click()` as much as possible.

Comment: The same problem occurs with adding/removing a class, so it's not just a :hover issue.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Only opacity on transition sucks.

Since that on iPhone you need to tap in order to focus an element this is how I've fixed my problem:

```
.mydiv {
        visibility:hidden;
        opacity: 0;
        transition: all 1s ease-out; 
        -webkit-transition: all 1s ease-out;
        -moz-transition: all 1s ease-out;
        -o-transition: all 1s ease-out;
}
.mydiv:hover {
            visibility:visible;
            opacity: 1;
}
.mydiv:active {
            -webkit-transition: opacity 1s ease-out;
}
```

I've added the opacity transition to :active.

This way it works with all transition animation (consider that you want to apply animation to height or something else) on Chrome, Firefox and iPhone (on tap).

Thanks to Grezzo and Michael Martin-Smucker for spotting out about the opacity transition.

(copy/paste of my response from [CSS animation visibility: visible; works on Chrome and Safari, but not on iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10736478/css-animation-visibility-visible-works-on-chrome-and-safari-but-not-on-ios/15057867#15057867))

Comment: +1, that's a clever solution to make this hacky "fix" only affect touch devices.

Comment: The bug (which impact iOS ≤ 7) can be fixed by specify a zero duration for visibility transition (+ correct delay): state1=`opacity: 1; visibility: visible; transition: opacity 1s, visibility 0s;` and state2=`opacity: 0; visibility: hidden; transition: opacity 1s, visibility 0s 1s;`

Answer (score 11):

With some minor modifications to the `transition` property, this can work on iOS. On `:hover`, limit the `transition` to only the `opacity` property, like so:

```
a:hover span {
    opacity:1;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 0.5s;
    transition: opacity 0.5s;
    visibility:visible;
}​
```

While [visibility is an animatable property](http://www.w3.org/TR/2013/WD-css3-transitions-20130212/#animatable-properties), there seems to be a bug in the iOS implementation. When you try to transition `visibility`, it seems like the entire transition doesn't happen. If you simply limit your transition to `opacity`, things work as expected.

**To be clear:** Leave the `visibility` property in your CSS, just don't try to transition it if you want things to work in Mobile Safari.

For reference, here's your updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jrpSJ/12/), which I tested on an iPad:

```css
a {
  background: gray;
  display: block;
  margin: 100px;
  padding: 100px;
}
a span {
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: 0.5s;
  visibility: hidden;
}
a:hover span {
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.5s;
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<a href="#">a <span>span</span></a>
```

Comment: The visibility property is important for accessibility. Opacity visually hides the element where visibility also hides it for screen readers.

Comment: Right, I'm not suggesting that you get rid of `visibility`, only that you don't try to `transition` it (which isn't possible anyway).

Comment: @MichaelMartin-Smucker You are a genius! I used your solution to fix a similar problem I was having: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10736478/css-animation-visibility-visible-works-on-chrome-and-safari-but-not-on-ios/10737773#10737773. I have answered my own question (and referenced your answer here), but I'm not sure my explanation of why it works is 100% correct, could you check on it and add a comment or submit an alternative answer if I got something wrong? Thank you so much.

Comment: Actually, 'visibility' is a valid animatable property. I've used it to help make some transitions more accessible.  http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-transitions/#animatable-properties

Comment: @ChrisB thanks, I've updated my answer. Out of curiosity, is there an accessibility benefit to transitioning `visibility` (instead of transitioning only `opacity` and simply toggling `visibility`)?

Comment: In the circumstance I used it in, I was transitioning height. And if you didn't transition the visibility, the element would immediately disappear (ruining the transition). I guess opacity does some sort of magic to prevent that. Strange. Demo here: http://cbateman.com/blog/accessible-css-transitions/

Comment: I had a similar issue and this answer solved my problem. I was attempting to `transition: all` on an element with both `opacity` and `visibility` applied. Interestingly, it was Chrome on iOS in which the transition failed altogether - the element in question stayed invisible; Safari simply failed to render the smooth opacity transition but did reveal the hidden element. Specifying `transition: opacity` fixed everything.