# How to style drop down list?

Tags: php, html, css, forms, drop-down-menu

How to add css styles to the drop down list on this form? I searched a lot over the internet but no useful results found.
Thanks

```
    echo  "<form method='post' action='advisor.php?view=$view'>
    Select Student: <select name='data'>";
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query))
        {

                    echo "<option value=\"".$row[3] . "\">".$row[0] ." " . $row[1] . " (".$row[3].")".
                    "</option>";
        }
      echo    " </select>
        <input type='submit' name='submit' class='buttonM' value='Show Questions' />
        </form>";
     }
```

Comment: What do you mean by style? What are you trying to make it look like?

Comment: "Style" is a little ambiguous; text color, background color, border, or make it look something like [uniform](http://uniformjs.com/)?

Comment: What have you tried? Are you looking for a pure-CSS or JS approach? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1895476/how-to-style-a-select-dropdown-with-css-only-without-javascript

Comment: I edited the question, I mean how to add css style to the drop down list.

Comment: Possible duplicate of: "[How to style a <select> dropdown with CSS only without JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1895476/1456376)"

Comment: But `<option>` is always a child of `<select>` and you also open a `<select>`-tag in the second line - which is never closed. What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @insertusernamehere sorry I deleted the comments, I wish if I know the best way to style the drop down list and if I got the idea I will add another effects to the drop down list.

Comment: As you see, you can't style a `<select>`-list that much. What you can do is to use an unsorted or sorted list to behave like a drop down list. This way you have all the possibilities CSS offers. The only downside is, that you have to use JavaScript. See my answer to this question, how it can be achieved: [How can I use <ul> list instead of <select> dropdown for the languages switcher?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14926603/1456376).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check this out - http://bavotasan.com/2011/style-select-box-using-only-css/

html

```
<div class="styled-select">
   <select>
      <option>Here is the first option</option>
      <option>The second option</option>
   </select>
</div>
```

css

```
.styled-select select {
   background: transparent;
   width: 268px;
   padding: 5px;
   font-size: 16px;
   line-height: 1;
   border: 0;
   border-radius: 0;
   height: 34px;
   -webkit-appearance: none;
}
```

For more elaborate styling you need to use javascript - like this http://tympanus.net/codrops/2012/10/04/custom-drop-down-list-styling/

Answer (score 0):

If what you mean is "How can I style the selectable options in a  form element?", then you're gonna have a hard time. You cannot use pure CSS to achieve that. You could create an "

" drop-down menu to achieve the visual effect you want, but that depends what your form is used for, really...

Comment: ok, how can I achieve that?