# How can I use <ul> list instead of <select> dropdown for adding images to every option?

Tags: javascript, html, css, symfony

I started with this code

```js
function OnChange(value) {
  var sum = 0;
  var x = document.getElementById("first").value;
  var y = document.getElementById("second").value;
  var z = document.getElementById("third").value;
  sum = parseInt(x) + parseInt(y) + parseInt(z);
  document.getElementById('sum').innerHTML = sum;
}
```

```html
<select id="first" onchange='OnChange(this.value)'>
  <option value="0">Choose...</option>
  {% for firstDigit in firstDigits %}
  <option value="{{ firstDigit.value }}">
    {{ firstDigit.name }}
  </option>
  {% endfor %}
</select>
<select id="second" onchange='OnChange(this.value)'>
  <option value="0">Choose...</option>
  {% for secondDigit in secondDigits %}
  <option value="{{ secondDigit.value }}">
    {{ secondDigit.name }}
  </option>
  {% endfor %}
</select>
<select id="third" onchange='OnChange(this.value)'>
  <option value="0">Choose...</option>
  {% for thirdDigit in thirdDigits %}
  <option value="{{ thirdDigit.value }}">
    {{ thirdDigit.name }}
  </option>
  {% endfor %}
</select>
```

and found this [How can I use <ul> list instead of <select> dropdown for the languages switcher?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14926368/how-can-i-use-ul-list-instead-of-select-dropdown-for-the-languages-switcher) for my changes, but I have sum which makes me hard to do. I made for every select option click function.

```
first.click(function (event){});
second.click(function (event){});
third.click(function (event){});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolve

```
 const updateTotal = function(){
        let total = 0;

        $("ol > li[data-value].active").each(function(){
            const value = parseInt(this.getAttribute("data-value"));
            if (!isNaN(value)) { total += value; }
        });

        $("#total").html(total);
        document.getElementById('eu').innerHTML = "eu";
    };

    $(document).on("click", "ol > li[data-value]", function(){
        const me = $(this);
        me.closest("ol").find("li").removeClass("active");
        me.addClass("active");
        updateTotal();
    });
```

Comment: How to create reset button for this resolve script ( above)?

Answer (score 0):

After spend some hours I just need to fix this every time when I choose different value the sum is increase with the new value. How to keep first choose and just replace the new value. What I mean for firstDigit I choose 10 for secondDigit 20, but when I change firstDigit to 20 the sum is 50 and this is not correct should be 40.

```js
const firstNav = $('#firsNav');
const firstSelection = $('.firstDigit');
const firstValue = firstSelection.find('li');

const secondNav = $('#secondNav');
const secondSelection = $('.secondDigit');
const secondValue = secondSelection.find('li')
var sum = 0;
firstNav.click(function(event) {
  if (firstNav.hasClass('active')) {
    firstNav.removeClass('active');
    selection.stop().slideUp(200);
  } else {
    firstNav.addClass('active');
    selection.stop().slideDown(200);
  }
  event.preventDefault();
});

secondNav.click(function(event) {
  if (secondNav.hasClass('active')) {
    secondNav.removeClass('active');
    secondSelection.stop().slideUp(200);
  } else {
    secondNav.addClass('active');
    secondSelection.stop().slideDown(200);
  }
  event.preventDefault();
});

firstValue.click(function() {
  firstValue.removeClass('active');
  $(this).addClass('active');
  var x = $(this).attr('data-value');
  sum = parseInt(x);
  document.getElementById('total').innerHTML = sum;
});

firstValue.click(function() {
  firstValue.removeClass('active');
  $(this).addClass('active');
  var z = $(this).attr('data-value');
  sum = parseInt(z);
  document.getElementById('total').innerHTML = sum;
})

document.getElementById('total').innerHTML = sum;
```

```css
/*ExteriorFin*/

ol.firstDigit {
  display: none;
}

ol.firstDigit>li {
  width: 200px;
  background: #eee;
  line-height: 25px;
  font-size: 14px;
  padding: 0 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

ol.firstDigit>li:hover {
  background: #aaa;
}


/*InteriorWallFin*/

ol.secondDigit {
  display: none;
}

ol.secondDigit>li {
  width: 200px;
  background: #eee;
  line-height: 25px;
  font-size: 14px;
  padding: 0 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

ol.secondDigit>li:hover {
  background: #aaa;
}
```

```html
<h2 id="firsNav">Choose</h2>
<ol class="firstDigit">
  <li data-value="10"> 10 </li>
  <li data-value="20"> 20 </li>
</ol>
<h2 id="secondNav">Choose</h2>
<ol class="secondDigit">
  <li data-value="10"> 10 </li>
  <li data-value="20"> 20 </li>
</ol>
<a id="total" style="font-size: large;font-weight: bold;color: #0a0a0a"></a>
```