# Dropdown menu not displaying on iPad

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, ipad, mobile-safari

I am having a problem with a site I am building where a dropdown menu isn't always getting displayed when viewed on an iPad.  The site can be found here:
http://bit.ly/RtGfPn

To see the menu the iPad should be in landscape orientation.  It is the navigation bar that is causing the problems (ie. Men, Women, Brands)

The dropdown menu seems to only work on some pages and even then it seems a little inconsistent.  It always seems fine on desktop browsers.

Does anyone have any ideas why the menu only displays sometimes?

Comment: Stumbled across this post with a solution that worked:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/10702958/239768

Answer (score 1):

I experienced a similar issue awhile back adding `"onClick="return true"` to my top level nav item seemed to force the sub menu to open.