# Input type radio isn't working on iPhone

Tags: javascript, html, css, iphone

I'm developing a website where I'm using an input with type "radio", but instead of the radio button I changed for a different image in each input. When I select an input on iPhone I'm not able to change for another input, even if I tap in another input it stays at the first input and I don't know why this is happening. Here is my html and CSS

```
<input type="radio" name="feeling" value="awesome" id="awesome"><label for="awesome"><span></span></label>
<input type="radio" name="feeling" value="normal" id="normal"><label for="normal"><span></span></label>
<input type="radio" name="feeling" value="bad" id="bad"><label for="bad"><span></span></label>

input[type="radio"] {
    display:none;
}

#awesome + label span {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 5rem;
    height: 5rem;
    vertical-align: middle;
    background: url(awesome.png) left top no-repeat;
    opacity: 0.6;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 300ms ease-out;
    -moz-transition: opacity 300ms ease-out;
    transition: opacity 300ms ease-out;
}


#normal + label span {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 5rem;
    height: 5rem;
    vertical-align: middle;
    background: url(normal.png) left top no-repeat;
    opacity: 0.6;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 300ms ease-out;
    -moz-transition: opacity 300ms ease-out;
    transition: opacity 300ms ease-out;
}

#bad + label span {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 5rem;
    height: 5rem;
    vertical-align: middle;
    background: url(bad.png) left top no-repeat;
    opacity: 0.6;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 300ms ease-out;
    -moz-transition: opacity 300ms ease-out;
    transition: opacity 300ms ease-out;
}

#bad + label, #normal + label, #awesome + label {
    margin: 1rem 2px;
} 

#awesome + label span:hover, #normal + label span:hover, #bad + label span:hover {
    opacity: 1;
}

#awesome:checked + label span, #normal:checked + label span, #bad:checked + label span {
    opacity: 1;
 }
```

I tried to change from one input to another in an Android phone and it seems to work perfectly.

Here is a Fiddle with my problem: http://jsfiddle.net/bhzabL20/

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I already tried to use label { cursor: pointer; } on CSS but it doesn't work and using onclick="" on the label and on the form it doesn't work either

Comment: try commenting or  removing the `:hover` effect on the `input`

Comment: Removing the :hover effect doesn't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try putting `onclick=""` on the `label` tags in html. If you don't have the label tags just add them so that they encompass a single radio choice each.

Comment: Note: The onclicks are supposed to be empty, in order to act as fake click detectors.

Comment: SO I need to remove the <span></span> inside of the label tags? Because I tried to put onclick="" on the label tags but it doesn't work

Comment: Try it. The spans are useless anyway because label has all their properties already, unless you have css specifically for span.

Answer (score 0):

I guess your "problem" has nothing to do with the `input`. It is more likely a problem with the opacity transition (and how to trigger) - see: [iOS CSS opacity + visibility transition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7548833/ios-css-opacity-visibility-transition)

BTW: Your CSS is very "redundant" - DRY.